# Element property doesnt exist on typescript simple project

Tags: typescript

Im doing my first TypeScript project, im getting this error on the "style", i tried to use style!, create a if(changeBackgroundColor){}, but it wont work.

```
let changeBackgroundColor = document.querySelectorAll(
      '[data-style="cart-thrash-side-bar-' +
        data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
        '"]'
    );
changeBackgroundColor.forEach(
  (element) =>
    (element.style.backgroundColor =
      data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].color)
);
```

Error: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: How does `changeBackgroundColor` get defined?

Comment: let changeBackgroundColor = document.querySelectorAll(
          '[data-style="cart-thrash-side-bar-' +
            data.types[whichLoteriaIsVar].type +
            '"]'
        );

Comment: I will edit on the post

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` is generic - pass `HTMLElement` to indicate that you're selecting HTMLElements rather than just Elements. ("Elements" alone don't have styles, but HTMLElements do)

```
let changeBackgroundColor = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(
```